# Decode part of JSON, but without producing array

Tags: php, arrays, json

So I have a very big JSON string that represents a multidimensional array with 255 entries, each entry, being an array with 255 other entries, liek this:

```
0 => array(0, 1, ..., 255),
1 => array(0, 1, ..., 255),

...
255 => array(0, 1, ..., 255),
```

(the only difference is that the values from the 2nd level are strings made out of 2-3 characters in my case)

Could I retrieve a certain value from this encoded string based on a key, but without actually decoding it to an array?

for example, I may want to get `$arr[37][78];`

To do this currently I'd have to:

```
$arr = json_decode($string);
$value = $arr[37][78];
```

Which I'd like to avoid because the decoded string takes a huge amount of memory as an array...

Comment: Is it really *that* huge when the items only contain 3 chars?

Comment: not all of them, some have more. But most of them have 3

Comment: It's theoretically possible, but I wouldn't want to go through that exercise.  Like pixeline said, regex, substring or manual parsing (ie, find the 37*255th opening bracket, etc.  Ugly.  Agree with Petra, you are looking at like < 200KB by my quick estimation.

Answer (score 1):

No, not based on a key. Since at the point that you receive it it's a string, your only option is regex or substr(), using indexes.